# Sorting a list of dates as a String in Java

Tags: java

I have a list of dates as String in my arrayList. I need to get the lowest date value from this list and then compare to the date which is in "dd-MM-yy" format. How can I do that??

Here is my code::

```
List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(DailyDataReading ddr: finalResult){
    dateList.add(sdf.format(ddr.getDailyReadingDate()));
}

Collections.sort(dateList);

if((sdf.format("date which is to be compared")).compareTo(dateList.get(dateList.size()-1))<=0)
 {...}
```

Comment: I see you added your code. That is great start. Now try to explain what you think this code should do/represent and how is it different than what you expected.

Comment: Actually i need the dates in descending order and i am not sure if this collections.sort() will return dates in descending order or a random order as the dates are in String format

Comment: `Collection.sort` without `Comparator` argument will try to use *natural* order (it will assume that all elements implement `Comparable` and will use order provided by `compareTo(other)` method). Anyway if you are looking for min/max then you don't need to sort all elements and usually one iteration over all elements should be enough to pick smallest/biggest.

Comment: It would be  very helpful if you can add two lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> dateList;// This is your list of dates in string format
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yy");// This is a formatter to convert from your pattern to a LocalDate
List<LocalDate> dates = dateList.stream().map(dateString -> LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateTimeFormatter)).collect(Collectors.toList());// Use Java 8 streams to map the dates strings to LocalDate objects
Collections.sort(dates);// Sort the list
LocalDate earliestDate = dates.get(0);// Take the lowest date value from the list
LocalDate specialDate = LocalDate.parse("some date", dateTimeFormatter);// create a date object for the date that you want to compare it to
earliestDate.compareTo(specialDate);// compare them
```

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are all date values in the form `dd-MM-yy`, and you want to sort those date strings in chronological order, assuming that all years are from this century (i.e. years 2000-2099), then this is how you do it.

```
Collections.sort(dateList, (d1,d2) -> {
    int cmp = d1.substring(6, 8).compareTo(d2.substring(6, 8));
    if (cmp == 0)
        cmp = d1.substring(3, 5).compareTo(d2.substring(3, 5));
    if (cmp == 0)
        cmp = d1.substring(0, 2).compareTo(d2.substring(0, 2));
    return cmp;
});
```

The *"lowest date value from this list"* is then the first value, i.e. `dateList.get(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Collections.sort(list_of_dates, new CustomComparator());
>
> ```
> public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {// MyObject would be Model class
>     Date date1,date2;
>     @Override
>     public int compare(MyObject obj1, MyObject obj2) {
>         DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd, MMM yyyy");
>         try {
>              date1 = df1.parse(obj1.getDate());
>              date2 = df1.parse(obj2.getDate());
>         } catch (ParseException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>         return date1.compareTo(date2);
>     }
> }
> ```

Collections.reverse(list_of_dates);

this will sort your list by newest first..